# Win 7 - Unable to launch EMC - W3SVC not running

Tags: windows, exchange-server-2010, emc

I've been banging my head against a wall here and can't seem to get this Exchange Management Console to work. First some stats...

Device: Windows 7 Pro - Service Pack 1 - x64
Software - Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 1 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21570

I've installed the World Wide Web Publishing Service and it shows as 'running' in the services window.

The error I get when I launch the EMC.

"The world wide web publishing service (W3SVC) isn't running on any exchange server in the site"

Well... I beg to differ WINDOWS... Anyway, I've been searching a solution for this for over an hour now, the majority say that the EMC version needs to match the Windows version. It does. They are both SP1... Any guidance here would be amazing!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Let's being like this, we need to get more precise  Error 1 - Windows 7 Pro - Service Pack 1 - x64 Software - Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 1  IS NOT A DEVICE, it's a  SOFTWARE ENVIRONMENT, Just saying,  Lets Save Time and Use the info you have already obtained from hours of research, You said Most of it says that the EMC Version NEEDS to match the Windows Version, So.. Let's start with the Error Message,     W3SVC is not running,   However You have Visually confirmed that the Service is running under Windows,  that means that the EMC is not communicating with SERVICES,  Now, You said that Most of your research leads to   EMC VERSION NEEEDS TO MATCH WINDOWS VERSION, then you stated "it does they are both Service Pack 1"  BE ADVISED  Service Packs ARE NOT Versions,  so let's now Please do some research and get back to me with the EMC version and the Windows Version  You can obtain windows version by going to SEARCH and typing   winver   We already know that your Using Windows 7 Professional 9 i assume 64bit) , so logically, Find out the Version of your EMC and Exchange server and you should be heading in the right direction, my guess is this will most likely fix your issue,  Keep in mind, Service Pack 1, is not a version, it's a Service Pac  Please do that first and then we can proceed,  My guess is that the Versions need to be the same in order to communicate with SERVICES,  Sound Logical,  get that done and i think you'll have yourself a solution. let me know how you go.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was a bit frustrated when I wrote that and the info was admittedly a bit poor. <Windows Version: 6.1 Build 7601: SP1> <EMC Version: 14.01.0218.013>

Comment: LOL, that's ok i know the feeling, OK give me 24 hours to research that for you, OK and i'll see what i can dig up OK,   Don't Stress, of the topic for a second,  I'm 40, when i was 16 i realised that Stress doesn't contribute to your Homeostasis in any POSITIVE way, it's just negative (and no, i'm not questioning your sexuality, LOL, Homeostasis refers to the Normal functionality of your body)  the point being.. i learned that Stress is irrelevant and you can eliminate it, it takes a few years and a little practice, but it can be done,  i'll look into this because i don't stress OK

Comment: in the meantime, from your end, to give us a direction to troubleshoot towards, i would be Looking at the Application Log and System Log on Exchange Server, and what events that occur around the same time as the error, there could be conflicts,  Also Let's keep in mind that Some Services require Dependancies , Services that are required to run for those services to work, so even though  World Wide Web Publishing services is running (and i would try STOP then START the service again, but even if it is, there may be another service it depends on that isnt running, have you explored this option ?

Comment: Here's an Idea, Since the problem Seems to be related to the Service packs , and i can now see What you were saying, Assuming YOU INSTALLED the Service Packs, Why not try uninstalling them and see if everything works, then install then again 1 by 1, if they are necessary, Let me know how that goes

Comment: Regarding your EMC Version  <EMC Version: 14.01.0218.013>, it starts with 14.01  the 14 indicates Exchange Server 2010, Now according to an aritcle im reading the 01 indicates no service pack, if it read 14.1 the .1 would be service pack,  also it is know that certain software in EMC can incorrectly report SP's and details of updates, Check ExSetup.exe version

Navigate to your exchange installation Bin directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Bin) and check ExSetup.exe file properties. Version will be listed in Version or Details tab. see if that tells a different story

Comment: this might prove helpful to you [http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/servers/219]

Comment: Let me know how yo go with all that ok

Comment: Nope, my bad, apparently in Exchange 2010  you can have both 14.1 and 14.01 and they both signify SP1,  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx]  i would say let's stick to trying to find the culprit of the Dependancy service, that's my gut feeling

Comment: i strongly recommend you try this [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236166/EN-US]  i think i'll stop troubleshooting here, until you give me the results of what happened after doing this solution. let me know.. be cool and don't stress

Comment: Thanks! TBH the first comment you made about versions got me thinking a bit more. First of all, I agree, stressing out solves nothing! I just got so optimistic when everything finally installed error free thinking I was free and clear only to be slapped down again... So I have installed this on another Win 7 X64 PC in the past and decided to hunt it down and take a look. It was using 14.03 so SP3... Makes sense. After a great deal of trial and error, I finally upgraded it, and VOLIA it is working! Thanks so much for your help and direction!

Comment: Firstly .. Your Welcome, Secondly.. 2 Words  MURPHY'S LAW  if it installs without error, question it. LOL  Third,  Stress Clouds the mind, Look at your mind like HDD Storage, Let's say you can hold 20GB of data and you use that data to process problems, Well, let's say you stress out and that takes up 5GB of Space, so.. you then only have 15GB to work with,  sometimes when your working on problem you need the extra stuff, but stress is in the way,  Having a meal also helps a huge deal, and Lastly GUIDANCE, that's exactly what i was trying to do, Good Work you got there in the end.